# how to clear date range picker values on Button on click?

Tags: javascript, typescript, antd, date-range

This is my code and I have date range picker and a clear button. when I click on the clear button the state get changed(changed to null values) and I want to show it in the UI. how can I set the value of date range picker to show it ?

```
const [para, _setPara] = useState({
  startDate: null,
  endDate:null
} as any);

const onChange =(date:any, dateString:any) =>{
    setPara({
      startDate:date[0].format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"),
      endDate: date[1].format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
    })
}

const clearSearch =()=>{
  setPara({
    startDate: null,
    endDate:null
  })
}

return(
<RangePicker onChange={onChange} allowClear={false} value={?} />
<Button
   type="primary"
   onClick={() => clearSearch()}
   danger
>
)
```

Comment: Did you try setting the value as blank?

Comment: Why don't you want to use the native clear button?

Comment: I have more inputs and want to use a clear button. That's why I don't want to use the native clear button @NadiaChibrikova

Comment: no I dont know how to set the value there ! thats what I'm asking @AmalDev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value you get in the `onChange` is in the same format as the component expects it, so you either need to keep it in the state as it is and convert to string when you need it, or you keep the string in the state and convert to the correct format on each render. You can pass the values in an array

```
<RangePicker onChange={onChange} allowClear={false} value={[moment1,moment2]} />
```

To create a moment from string you need to import `moment` and call it with the date format you're using:

```
import moment from 'moment';
...
const moment1=moment(startDate,"YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
```

to clear just set the both moments to `null`